# How to hide cell with code Jupyter notebook

Tags: anaconda, markdown

I am using jupyter notebook to create a report.I would like when converting the notebook to PDF not to show the code in the PDF file. I have tried using remove_cell in the cell tag. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Tried [hide_code](https://github.com/kirbs-/hide_code)?

Comment: Thanks I have tried this extension but when i convert to PDF i can still see the code. The way i am exporting to PDF is using File > Download > PDF via Latex.

Comment: It says [here](https://github.com/kirbs-/hide_code/issues/79) to use the choices in new download menu that it adds. Maybe you'll have better results with those? Especially since  [there is a big discussed presently](https://github.com/kirbs-/hide_code/issues/65) with latex PDF export.

Comment: When i try the new menu i get an 404 error message that say you have requested a page that doesn't exists! Any idea why would this be the case.

Comment: Oops, I meant 'there is a bug' in my last comment. Do you get that error message with all the items listed in the new menu or just that one? You have both pdfkit & wkhtmltopdf installed? That was the suggestion to check [here](https://github.com/kirbs-/hide_code/issues/76). Maybe look [here](https://github.com/kirbs-/hide_code/issues/72) too?

Comment: Thanks for your help! By setting up the directory and installing wkhtmltopdf that seem to fix the issue. i can now import to PDF without any issues.

Comment: Did you try [nbdev](https://github.com/fastai/nbdev) for this?